# THREE.js reposition vertices for RingGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Codepen is available here: http://codepen.io/pehrlich/pen/CogjG

I want to render a ring geometry in the scene, and then dynamically change it's arcLength (thetaLength).  To start with, I'm calling it's constructor, and then recalling the code which positions the vertices.  However, this causes strange results.

Here's the method call - essentially copied from the constructor and given a new name of setThetaLength:

```
THREE.RingGeometry.prototype.setThetaLength = function(thetaLength){

//  this.thetaLength = thetaLength;


  var i, o, uvs = [], radius = this.innerRadius, radiusStep = ( ( this.outerRadius - this.innerRadius ) / this.phiSegments );

    for ( i = 0; i < this.phiSegments + 1; i ++ ) { // concentric circles inside ring

        for ( o = 0; o < this.thetaSegments + 1; o ++ ) { // number of segments per circle

            var vertex = this.vertices[i + o]; // maybe i need to query vertex indices here.
            var segment = this.thetaStart + o / this.thetaSegments * this.thetaLength;
            vertex.x = radius * Math.cos( segment );
            vertex.y = radius * Math.sin( segment );

//          uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( ( vertex.x / this.outerRadius + 1 ) / 2, ( vertex.y / this.outerRadius + 1 ) / 2 ) );
        }

        radius += radiusStep;

    }


    this.computeFaceNormals();

    this.boundingSphere = new THREE.Sphere( new THREE.Vector3(), radius );

  this.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}
```

Here's the original draw, and what I expect after calling `setThetaLength` without changing thetaLength:

[image]

Here's the image, after the call:

[image]

What's going on?  Is THREE caching some information, or changing vertex order in unexpected ways?

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/pehrlich/pen/CogjG

Edit: it does indeed look like vertex ordering.  If I force vertex order, then I can rearrange ok.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  Was having an off by one error when looping through segments.

Here is a complete method to change the phi of a THREE.JS sphere:

```
THREE.SphereGeometry.prototype.setPhiLength = function(phiLength){

  this.parameters.phiLength = phiLength;

  var heightSegments  = this.parameters.heightSegments,
      widthSegments   = this.parameters.widthSegments,
      radius          = this.parameters.radius,
      phiStart        = this.parameters.phiStart,
      thetaLength     = this.parameters.thetaLength,
      thetaStart      = this.parameters.thetaStart;


  var x, y;

    for ( y = 0; y <= heightSegments; y ++ ) {

        for ( x = 0; x <= widthSegments; x ++ ) {

            var u = x / widthSegments;
            var v = y / heightSegments;

            var vertex = this.vertices[(y * (widthSegments + 1)) + x];
            vertex.x = - radius * Math.cos( phiStart + u * phiLength ) * Math.sin( thetaStart + v * thetaLength );
            vertex.y = radius * Math.cos( thetaStart + v * thetaLength );
            vertex.z = radius * Math.sin( phiStart + u * phiLength ) * Math.sin( thetaStart + v * thetaLength );


        }

    }

  this.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

};
```